# giltab don`t start redis

Tags: centos, gitlab

I`m installing gitlab on centos 7 using this tutorial https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/centos-7_3/install/centos

```
# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

Command:

```
[root@localhost gitlab]# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

Somehow dont want to work and shows message:

> == Seed from /home/git/gitlab/db/fixtures/production/001_admin.rb
>       2014-10-09T07:19:06Z 1911 TID-orwz1bspw INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {:url=>"unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock",
>   :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
>       rake aborted!
>       Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - connect(2) for /var/run/redis/redis.sock

full log:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
This will create the necessary database tables and seed the database.
You will lose any previous data stored in the database.
Do you want to continue (yes/no)? yes

gitlabhq_production already exists
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0014s
-- create_table("broadcast_messages", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0608s
-- create_table("deploy_keys_projects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0331s
-- add_index("deploy_keys_projects", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_deploy_keys_projects_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.1857s
-- create_table("emails", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0224s
-- add_index("emails", ["email"], {:name=>"index_emails_on_email", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0586s
-- add_index("emails", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_emails_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0916s
-- create_table("events", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0495s
-- add_index("events", ["action"], {:name=>"index_events_on_action", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0423s
-- add_index("events", ["author_id"], {:name=>"index_events_on_author_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.1521s
-- add_index("events", ["created_at"], {:name=>"index_events_on_created_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- add_index("events", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_events_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("events", ["target_id"], {:name=>"index_events_on_target_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("events", ["target_type"], {:name=>"index_events_on_target_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- create_table("forked_project_links", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0390s
-- add_index("forked_project_links", ["forked_to_project_id"], {:name=>"index_forked_project_links_on_forked_to_project_id", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0777s
-- create_table("issues", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0389s
-- add_index("issues", ["assignee_id"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_assignee_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0691s
-- add_index("issues", ["author_id"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_author_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- add_index("issues", ["created_at"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_created_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("issues", ["milestone_id"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_milestone_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0583s
-- add_index("issues", ["project_id", "iid"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_project_id_and_iid", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0668s
-- add_index("issues", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0664s
-- add_index("issues", ["title"], {:name=>"index_issues_on_title", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- create_table("keys", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0329s
-- add_index("keys", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_keys_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0586s
-- create_table("label_links", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0306s
-- add_index("label_links", ["label_id"], {:name=>"index_label_links_on_label_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0526s
-- add_index("label_links", ["target_id", "target_type"], {:name=>"index_label_links_on_target_id_and_target_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- create_table("labels", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0412s
-- add_index("labels", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_labels_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0586s
-- create_table("merge_request_diffs", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0305s
-- add_index("merge_request_diffs", ["merge_request_id"], {:name=>"index_merge_request_diffs_on_merge_request_id", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.1610s
-- create_table("merge_requests", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0327s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["assignee_id"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_assignee_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0753s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["author_id"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_author_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0835s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["created_at"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_created_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0641s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["milestone_id"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_milestone_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0772s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["source_branch"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_source_branch", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0728s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["source_project_id"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_source_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0688s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["target_branch"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_target_branch", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0747s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["target_project_id", "iid"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_target_project_id_and_iid", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0664s
-- add_index("merge_requests", ["title"], {:name=>"index_merge_requests_on_title", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0748s
-- create_table("milestones", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0411s
-- add_index("milestones", ["due_date"], {:name=>"index_milestones_on_due_date", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0586s
-- add_index("milestones", ["project_id", "iid"], {:name=>"index_milestones_on_project_id_and_iid", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- add_index("milestones", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_milestones_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- create_table("namespaces", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0329s
-- add_index("namespaces", ["name"], {:name=>"index_namespaces_on_name", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0586s
-- add_index("namespaces", ["owner_id"], {:name=>"index_namespaces_on_owner_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- add_index("namespaces", ["path"], {:name=>"index_namespaces_on_path", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0749s
-- add_index("namespaces", ["type"], {:name=>"index_namespaces_on_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0749s
-- create_table("notes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0286s
-- add_index("notes", ["author_id"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_author_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0596s
-- add_index("notes", ["commit_id"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_commit_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("notes", ["created_at"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_created_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0581s
-- add_index("notes", ["noteable_id", "noteable_type"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_noteable_id_and_noteable_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("notes", ["noteable_type"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_noteable_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("notes", ["project_id", "noteable_type"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_project_id_and_noteable_type", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("notes", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("notes", ["updated_at"], {:name=>"index_notes_on_updated_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0749s
-- create_table("projects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0412s
-- add_index("projects", ["creator_id"], {:name=>"index_projects_on_creator_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0504s
-- add_index("projects", ["last_activity_at"], {:name=>"index_projects_on_last_activity_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0664s
-- add_index("projects", ["namespace_id"], {:name=>"index_projects_on_namespace_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0667s
-- add_index("projects", ["star_count"], {:name=>"index_projects_on_star_count", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0581s
-- create_table("protected_branches", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0425s
-- add_index("protected_branches", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_protected_branches_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0503s
-- create_table("services", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0329s
-- add_index("services", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_services_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0669s
-- create_table("snippets", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0328s
-- add_index("snippets", ["author_id"], {:name=>"index_snippets_on_author_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0645s
-- add_index("snippets", ["created_at"], {:name=>"index_snippets_on_created_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- add_index("snippets", ["expires_at"], {:name=>"index_snippets_on_expires_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0581s
-- add_index("snippets", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_snippets_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0582s
-- create_table("taggings", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0352s
-- add_index("taggings", ["tag_id"], {:name=>"index_taggings_on_tag_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0479s
-- add_index("taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], {:name=>"index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0772s
-- create_table("tags", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0328s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0249s
-- add_index("users", ["admin"], {:name=>"index_users_on_admin", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0588s
-- add_index("users", ["authentication_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_authentication_token", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0748s
-- add_index("users", ["confirmation_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_confirmation_token", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("users", ["current_sign_in_at"], {:name=>"index_users_on_current_sign_in_at", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0664s
-- add_index("users", ["extern_uid", "provider"], {:name=>"index_users_on_extern_uid_and_provider", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index("users", ["name"], {:name=>"index_users_on_name", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0749s
-- add_index("users", ["reset_password_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0665s
-- add_index("users", ["username"], {:name=>"index_users_on_username", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0749s
-- create_table("users_groups", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0432s
-- add_index("users_groups", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_users_groups_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0668s
-- create_table("users_projects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0411s
-- add_index("users_projects", ["project_access"], {:name=>"index_users_projects_on_project_access", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0650s
-- add_index("users_projects", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_users_projects_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0602s
-- add_index("users_projects", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_users_projects_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0581s
-- create_table("users_star_projects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0329s
-- add_index("users_star_projects", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_users_star_projects_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0669s
-- add_index("users_star_projects", ["user_id", "project_id"], {:name=>"index_users_star_projects_on_user_id_and_project_id", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0645s
-- add_index("users_star_projects", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_users_star_projects_on_user_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0602s
-- create_table("web_hooks", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0247s
-- add_index("web_hooks", ["project_id"], {:name=>"index_web_hooks_on_project_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0899s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0934s
Adding limits to schema.rb for mysql
-- change_column(:merge_request_diffs, :st_commits, :text, {:limit=>2147483647})
   -> 0.0636s
-- change_column(:merge_request_diffs, :st_diffs, :text, {:limit=>2147483647})
   -> 0.0666s
-- change_column(:snippets, :content, :text, {:limit=>2147483647})
   -> 0.0666s
-- change_column(:notes, :st_diff, :text, {:limit=>2147483647})
   -> 0.0600s

== Seed from /home/git/gitlab/db/fixtures/production/001_admin.rb
2014-10-09T07:19:06Z 1911 TID-orwz1bspw INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {:url=>"unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - connect(2) for /var/run/redis/redis.sock
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:46:in `eval'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:149:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:178:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:273:in `establish_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:292:in `ensure_connected'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:179:in `block in process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:258:in `logging'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:178:in `process'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis.rb:1396:in `block in zadd'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.0.6/lib/redis.rb:1393:in `zadd'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.4.1/lib/redis/namespace.rb:352:in `method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:152:in `block in raw_push'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/connection_pool-1.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:55:in `with'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq.rb:67:in `redis'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:150:in `raw_push'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:50:in `push'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:98:in `push'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:83:in `client_push'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-2.17.0/lib/sidekiq/extensions/generic_proxy.rb:19:in `method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/app/services/notification_service.rb:110:in `new_user'
/home/git/gitlab/app/models/user.rb:500:in `post_create_hook'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:483:in `block in save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:502:in `block (2 levels) in around_save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:150:in `block in run_actions'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:170:in `catch_exceptions'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:148:in `run_actions'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:133:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:212:in `run_callbacks'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:186:in `within_transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:502:in `block in around_save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:530:in `block in transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:529:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:501:in `around_save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:483:in `save'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
(eval):7:in `block (2 levels) in run_file'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:46:in `eval'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in run_file'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:58:in `block in open'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:57:in `open'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:57:in `open'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:36:in `block in run_file'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:35:in `run_file'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:26:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:25:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu/runner.rb:25:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/seed-fu.rb:29:in `seed'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/seed-fu-2.3.1/lib/tasks/seed_fu.rake:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:19:in `setup_db'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed_fu
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have permission problems. So, execute these following comands :

```
$ echo -e 'unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock\nunixsocketperm 775' | sudo tee -a /etc/redis.conf
$ sudo chown redis:redis /var/run/redis
$ sudo chmod g+w  /var/run/redis
```

and then restart your redis service :

```
$service redis restart
```

(if it doesn't work, set the command to 777)

Answer (score 0):

This is a branch to update Centos6 for gitlab 7.3, not for Centos7.

There is however a [pending MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/merge_requests/28) which you can give a try and give your feedback.